# 32-bit Visual C++ client fails to instantiate a COM class implemented with .NET Core targeting "Any CPU"

Tags: c#, .net-core, com, interop, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to debug a COM server targeting .NET Core 3.1 with platform set to "Any CPU". I have a class decorated with `ComVisible` and `Guid` attributes, I have `<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>` in the .csproj. When I build the project I get all the files mentioned in [Exposing .NET Core components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com) and after I run `regsvr32` the registry is properly updated and `InprocServer32` is set to `My.Namespace.comhost.dll`.

The C++ side invokes `CoCreateInstance()`:

```
IUnknown* ptr;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, 0, CLSCTX_ALL, iid, (void**)&ptr);
```

If the client is compiled as a 64-bit application then the call succeeds. If it's compiled as a 32-bit application the call fails with "Class not registered" despite the fact that `InprocServer32` is set in both `HKCR\CLSID\{class-id-value}` and `HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{class-id-value}` (which is the standard approach to have two versions of the same COM server).

However if I target the COM server to "x86" instead of "Any CPU" platform and then recompile it (with exactly the same file path and name for the assembly) then the C++ client can instantiate it no problem.

So:

- 64-bit C++ client can instantiate the "Any CPU" COM server
- 32-bit C++ client cannot instantiate the "Any CPU" COM server
- 32-bit C++ client can instantiate the "x86" COM server

Sure I can craft a workaround - have two projects with "frontend" COM servers or perhaps have two configurations which would build the same project twice or something else such that the same COM server is exposed as both a "x64" and a "x86" assembly. It'd be better to make the "Any CPU" version just work.

Isn't there a more direct way to have "Any CPU" class library be consumed from both 32-bit and 64-bit COM clients?

Comment: I'm not familiar with .NET Core. But with regular .NET, you usually use regasm and not regsvr32. Also, with regular .NET, you use 64-bit regasm to register for the 64-bit hive and you use 32-bit regasm.exe to register for 32-bit hive. With regular .NET, to be able to use AnyCPU, you have to have two registrations. But, it does work. IDK what is changed for .NET core. Maybe my comment will be helpful...or not?

Comment: With (current) .NET core, there are a number of places where we have lost the coolness of "Any CPU". A .NET core COM object needs a native "[project].comhost.dll" file which is *never* Any CPU. So, "Any CPU" in this case is a big joke (not that fun): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32493

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A COM client cannot load IL directly so there's always some intermediary that loads the IL code and transforms it into native code.

With .NET Framework it was mscoree.dll which is installed in \windows\system32, is quite stable, and ships with Windows for quite a time now I think. So it's common to all .NET Framework COM (in process) objects

With .NET Core, there's a native host that, unfortunately or not, must be shipped with the project, it's called [project].comhost.dll.

The "Any Cpu" / "x86" / "x64" choice do influences this for the .NET assemby, but it cannot support the "Any Cpu" setting for the comhost.dll, it *must be x86 or x64*.

Here's a small visual:

[image]

The underlying design idea is IMHO to maximize loose coupling between .NET (core) and the OS (here Windows). It definitely has some drawbacks, it's not limited to COM.

Here is a discussion on this subject on the official dotnet github: [Support dual comhost.dll (x86, x64) generation for .NET Core assemblies using "Any CPU](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32493)